# Por um objeto definido está dando o erro de indefinido no angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Estou obtendo um erro ao efetuar o seguinte teste:

```
it('testing if the onStateChangeErrorHandle function is defined', function(){
  expect(rootScope.$on).toBeDefined();              
  srv.onStateChangeError({$rootScope: rootScope});
});
```

**ERRO:**

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'rootScope.$on')

E não estou percebendo o porque.

Comment: definiu rootScope anteriomente? se não use $rootScope

Comment: @FelipeDuarte está definido sim.  rootScope = $rootScope;